# Suggestion on Single Level Of Abstraction per Function - Java

Tags: java

I followed the SLAP principle in the below code.

But with "Mixing Level Of Abstraction" (refer below code) I can avoid the single line methods.

My question is - is it good to avoid the single line method in this case? But I believe the code with "SLAP Principle" has better readability than the other one. Please share your suggestions.

SLAP Principle:

```
public class TestAccount {
    private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "test_default";

    public void modify(Creditor creditor) {
        PartyDetails partyDetails = generatePartyDetails();
        assignPartyDetails(creditor, partyDetails);
    }

    private PartyDetails generatePartyDetails() {
        PartyDetails partyDetails = new PartyDetails();
        OrganisationIdentification orgId = generateOrgIdDetails();
        assignOrgIdValueToId(orgId, party6Choice);
        return partyDetails;
    }

    private OrganisationIdentification generateOrgIdDetails() {
        OrganisationIdentification orgId = new OrganisationIdentification();
        OtherIssueDetails otherIssuerDetails = generateIssuerDetails();
        assignOtherIssuerDetailsToOrgIdList(otherIssuerDetails, orgId);
        return orgId;
    }

    private OtherIssuerDetails generateIssuerDetails() {
        OtherIssuerDetails otherIssuerDetails =
                new OtherIssuerDetails();
        otherIssuerDetails.setIssr(DEFAULT_VALUE);
        return otherIssuerDetails;
    }

    private void assignOtherIssuerDetailsToOrgIdList(OtherIssuerDetails
                                                             otherIssuerDetails,
                                                     OrganisationIdentification
                                                             orgId) {
        orgId.getOthr().add(otherIssuerDetails);
    }

    private void assignOrgIdValueToId(OrganisationIdentification orgId,
                                      PartyDetails id) {
        id.setOrgId(orgId);
    }

    private void assignPartyDetails(Creditor creditor,
                                    PartyDetails partyDetails) {
        creditor.setId(partyDetails);
    }
}
```

Mixed Level Of Abstraction:

```
public class TestAccount {
    private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "test_default";

    public void modify(final Creditor creditor) {
        PartyDetails partyDetails = generatePartyDetails();
        creditor.setId(partyDetails);
    }

    private PartyDetails generatePartyDetails() {
        PartyDetails partyDetails = new PartyDetails();
        OrganisationIdentification orgId = generateOrgIdDetails();
        id.setOrgId(orgId);
        return partyDetails;
    }

    private OrganisationIdentification generateOrgIdDetails() {
        OrganisationIdentification orgId = new OrganisationIdentification();
        OtherIssuerDetails otherIssuerDetails = generateIssuerDetails();
        orgId.getOthr().add(otherIssuerDetails);
        return orgId;
    }

private OtherIssuerDetails generateIssuerDetails() {
        OtherIssuerDetails otherIssuerDetails =
                new OtherIssuerDetails();
        otherIssuerDetails.setIssr(DEFAULT_VALUE);
        return otherIssuerDetails;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your question Is going to produce opinion based answers. Which Is off topic. Further your code seems hypothetical, untested and not working.

Comment: @slepic I disagree. The question is narrow: "is it good to avoid the single line method in this case?" If there's anything bringing this question off-topic, it's that the code is a snippet, not presented in the context of the larger application.

Comment: Further, there's nothing to suggest that the code does not work.

Comment: I have provided this as a sample code. Because it is part of an application. If I have to provide the working code , then i can create a sample one. Please let me know.

Comment: [Details matter! In order to give good advice, we need to see real, concrete code, and understand the context in which the code is used.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)